# how to sort multidimensional Array in java logically?

Tags: java, arrays

i need to sort a multidimensional Array without going for any predefined method, it will be logically..

int arr[][]={{5,2,3},{2,8,5},{7,4,5}};

## in the case of single dimensional Array,

int num[]={125,28,31,40,12};

```
for(int i=0;i<=num.length-1;i++){
    for(int k=0;k<=num.length-2;k++){
         if(num[k]>num[k+1]){   
            int temp=0;    
            temp=num[k];    
            num[k]=num[k+1];    
            num[k+1]=temp;    
            }               
    }    
}
for(int s=0;s<=num.length-1;s++){
    System.out.println(num[s]);         
}
```

what would be in case of multidimensional array?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour], have a look around, and read through the [help], in particular [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask) Define "logically," and "without any predefined method." (It's really awkward to write software without defining a method for what you want to do in advance.) Show your expected outputs. Show your work trying to do this "logically."

Comment: If by "predefined method" you're referring to methods like `Collections.sort()` or `Arrays.sort()`, then your question is really "how do I sort data?" and that is way **too broad** a topic for here. Search the web for sorting algorithms. --- As for "logically", you haven't defined what *logic* you have in mind, so how would you expect us to help you? Do you want us to *guess* what you want result to be? That's not very *logical*, is it?

Comment: thanks for your suggestion,the question was asked for learning purpose.

Comment: Here are potential desired results of a sort that I can think of: 1) Sort rows in entirety: `{{2,8,5},{5,2,3},{7,4,5}}` --- 2) Sort cells of each row independently: `{{2,3,5},{2,5,8},{4,5,7}}` --- 3) Sort cells by lines then by rows: `{{2,2,3},{4,5,5},{5,7,8}}` --- 4) Sort cells by rows then by lines: `{{2,4,5},{2,5,7},{3,5,8}}`. --- I wonder which one is "logical" to you, or did you have something else in mind?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
public static void main(String[] args) {
        int u, arr[][] = {{1, 7, 2}, {9, 12}, {54, 25, 10}};
        for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < arr[i].length; j++) {
                for (int k = j + 1; k < arr[i].length; k++) {
                    if (arr[i][j] > arr[i][k]) {
                        u = arr[i][k];
                        arr[i][k] = arr[i][j];
                        arr[i][j] = u;
                    }
                }
                System.out.print(arr[i][j] + ",");
            }
            System.out.println(" ");
        }
 }
```